# How to secure the jdbc connection to Teradata DB

Tags: jdbc, teradata

To enable the data encryption in motion, how should we encrypt the JDBC connection to TeraData DB?

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Append the `ENCRYPTDATA=ON` option to the URL

Comment: thanks so much, Sir. Can you share the sample connection string for reference?  jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<service_name>:ENCRYPTDATA=ON

Comment: jdbc:teradata://<server>/ENCRYPTDATA=ON  See the [Teradata JDBC Driver Reference](https://downloads.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html)